# Inject property value into java validation error message

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, bean-validation

I want to include more information in my validation messages, such as the ID of the class being evaluated. For example:

```
class Clown {

int id;

@Min(value=15, message="Clown id:{id}'s shoe size should be greater than 15"
int shoeSize;
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this, with or without defining custom validators, either in javax or Hibernate?

If not, can you suggest any other validation frameworks that could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Validator has the notion of [HibernateConstraintValidatorContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-hibernateconstraintvalidatorcontext) which allows you to bind custom variables into the EL context prior to message interpolation. You can get the HibernateConstraintValidatorContext in your constraint validator implementation via:

```
HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext = context.unwrap( HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class );
```

This implies, however, that you can get hold of the value you want to bind in the constraint validator. Not sure you can do that in your case. You somehow want to get the clown id at this point, but you don't have access to the full clown instance in a field constraint validator. I guess you could use a class level constraint. In this case you would have access to the id, but on the other hand you would need to do the min check programmatically and you could not use @Min.